# How to optimise reading variables with Java.util.Scanner in this code?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The problem is to write a program that reads an expression like "number + operator + number" that a user is entering from keyboard. Possible operators are +, -, *, and /. The output should be the solution to this expression. Program should keep asking for new expressions until user inputs 0 for the first number. While numbers and operators are legit, program keeps asking for new expressions to crunch.

The program calculates everything properly, but I feel like there is a way to make reading variables more efficient. For example, there must be a way to read a variable for operator as a char, but `op = scr.next();` uses the whole String, which consumes more memory. ALso, `firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(scr.next());` - I feel like there is a more elegant way to to pass a double but can't wrap my head around it.

Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

````
public class simpleCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        double firstNumber, secondNumber;
        double value;
        String op;

        System.out.println("Enter a number followed by operator followed by another number:");
        System.out.println("such as  2 + 2  or  34.2 * 7.81:");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("? ");
            firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(scr.next());
            if (firstNumber == 0)
                break;
            op = scr.next();
            secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(scr.next());
            switch (op) {
                case "+":
                    value = firstNumber + secondNumber;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    value = firstNumber - secondNumber;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    value = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    value = firstNumber / secondNumber;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Unknown operator: " + op);
                    continue;
            } // end switch
            System.out.println("The value of the expression is " + value);
        }
        System.out.println("Bye-bye user!");
    }
}```
````

Comment: In a perfect world, if the user input does not have spaces before or after operator, the expression should be evaluated, too, but I feel like it's a whole different approach that would require to parse a string into chars and process it char by char...

Comment: Note that `Scanner` has a `nextDouble()` method .

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is very slow because it does a lot of parsing, regex searching, and much more. It’s a useful tool but when it comes to efficiency there are much better alternatives.

A much faster solution is to use a `BufferedReader` with a `StringTokenizer`.

Even faster you could read the data directly using a `DataInputStream` or a `BufferedInputStream`, but that is significantly more code to write than the BufferedReader with very minor performance increase.

I would post some code for you to use, but I’m on mobile, so I’ll update my post later with some examples, but the java docs are a great place to start.